# How can you pre-calculate the balls trajectory and therefore its endpoint in the game Pong?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making the classic Pong in Python, but I am in need of help.

For/in this game I want to calculate the trajectory of the ball, so for a given beginPoint(bounce on the left paddle) and angle(green thing) I want to calculate the endpoint(The blue X). This all in order to move the right paddle to the ball so you can play Pong on your own.

Here is an image of the problem to make it more clear:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtX5m.jpg

I've tried to come up with some type of algorithm using trigonometry, but could only calculate the first point and then get stuck:

```py
def calculateTragectory(beginY, angle):
    distanceX = 0
    direction = ball.directionY
    while True:
        if direction == -1:
            distanceX += (height - beginY) * math.tan(angle)
            direction == 1
        elif direction == 1:
            distanceX += beginY * math.tan(angle)
            direction == -1
```

Here is the rest of the code:

```py
import pygame
import random
import math
pygame.init()

width = 1000
height = 600

leftScore = 0
rightScore = 0
delay = 2
paddleSpeed = 2
ballSpeed = 1

paddleWidth = 15
paddleHeight = 70

ballRadius = 10

spacingX = 3*paddleWidth

window = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 128)

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, side):
        # left = true, right = false
        if side:
            self.x = spacingX
        else: self.x = width-spacingX
        self.y = 300

    def move(self, UpOrDown):
        if UpOrDown:
            self.y -= paddleSpeed
        else: self.y += paddleSpeed

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y, paddleWidth, paddleHeight))

class Ball():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = width/2
        self.y = height/2
        self.directionX = -1
        self.directionY = 1
    def move(self):
        if self.y > height or self.y < 0:
            self.directionY *=-1
        self.x += ballSpeed*self.directionX
        self.y += ballSpeed*self.directionY
    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255), (int(self.x), int(self.y)), ballRadius)
    def reset(self):
        self.x = width/2
        self.y = random.uniform(50, 550)
        self.directionX *= -1
def keyInput():
    # Key inputs True = Up, down is False
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w] and leftPaddle.y > 0:
        leftPaddle.move(True)
    if keys[pygame.K_s] and leftPaddle.y < height - paddleHeight:
        leftPaddle.move(False)
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        ball.x = width/2
        ball.y = height/2

def collisionDetection():
    if ball.x == leftPaddle.x + paddleWidth + ballRadius and leftPaddle.y <= ball.y <= leftPaddle.y + paddleHeight:
        ball.directionX *= -1
    if ball.x == computerPaddle.x - ballRadius and computerPaddle.y <= ball.y <= computerPaddle.y + paddleHeight:
        ball.directionX *= -1

def scoreUpdate():
    global rightScore, leftScore
    if ball.x <= 0:
        rightScore += 1
        ball.reset()
    elif ball.x >= width:
        leftScore +=1
        ball.reset()
def calculateTragectory(beginY, angle):
    distanceX = 0
    direction = ball.directionY
    while True:
        if direction == -1:
            distanceX += (height - beginY) * math.tan(angle)
            direction == 1
        elif direction == 1:
            distanceX += beginY * math.tan(angle)
            direction == -1

    a = beginPoint * math.tan(angle)

#Init paddles
leftPaddle = Paddle(True)
computerPaddle = Paddle(False)
ball = Ball()
#Game loop:
while True:
    pygame.time.delay(delay)
    ball.move()
    collisionDetection()
    scoreUpdate()
    scoreText_left = font.render(str(leftScore), True, (255, 255, 255))
    scoreText_right = font.render(str(rightScore), True, (255, 255, 255))
    keyInput()
    window.fill((0, 0, 0))
    window.blit(scoreText_left, (350-64, 50))
    window.blit(scoreText_right, (650, 50))
    leftPaddle.draw()
    computerPaddle.y = ball.y
    computerPaddle.draw()
    ball.draw()
    pygame.display.update()

    #Exit
    for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
         if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
             pygame.quit()
```

Comment: If the ball travels in a straight line, you should just calculate the intersection of its ray with the boundary lines of the field (and keep the nearest result).  Then repeat if it was a wall to find the next endpoint until it’s on the AI’s side.

Answer (score 2):

the following is the code you need:

```py
# width and height are the width and height you want to calculate the endpoint for
def calculate_tragectory(begin_y, angle):
    x_speed = math.cos(angle)  # calculate the relative x of the angle
    y_speed = math.sin(angle)  # calculate the relative y of the angle
    
    straight_pos = begin_y + width * y_speed / x_speed
    # this is the final position if the ball wouldn't change direction
    
    final_pos = abs(straight_pos) % (2 * height)
    # a negative result just of straight_pos means it bounces one additional time
    # but has no effect on the result.
    # (that's why abs(straight_pos) instead of just straight_pos)
    # if the result is 2 * height it means that the ball has bounced twice
    # and has returned to y position 0.
    
    if final_pos > height:
        final_pos = 2 * height - final_pos
    # if final_pos > height this means that the ball has bounced once and
    # the final position is the remainder to 2 * height.
    
    return final_pos
```

modifications you want to make:

- you need to subtract the paddle spacing as well as the ball radius from the width.
- make sure to set the **middle** of the paddle to this value not the top.
- in your case you don't actually want to input an angle but rather x and y speeds:

```py
def calculate_tragectory(begin_y, x_speed, y_speed):
    # input x_speed and y_speed instead of calculating them from the angle
    ...
```

general tips to improve your code:

- according to the [python documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) variables and function should be named lowercase_with_underscores
- the collision detection is quite crappy. it often visually collided but still went through the paddle.